# Postgresql - "Returning" the "inserted" row as json after an Insert

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to use the "RETURNING" keyword after an INSERT statement to allow to return the inserted row data as json - I want all the fields. Here is what I tried with no success:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createUser(  
  email_f character varying(50),  
  nickname_f character varying(16)
) RETURNS json AS $$  
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO users (email,nickname)  
    SELECT email_f,nickname_f  
    RETURNING row_to_json(row(*));  
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This gives me an error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "*"

What could I be doing wrong here? I would like to continue using the "Returning" keyword as it seems to be the best way to go about it - provided I can get it to work...

Comment: Hmmm, I seem to have what appears to be 2 correct answers to my question - first from @Houari then followed by Craig Ringer. I haven't decided which method I will settle with but would like to acknowledge both as being correct - I don't think I can check more than one answer.

Answer (score 5):

You may have more success with:

```
row_to_json(users.*)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it properly using a middle variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createUser(  
  email_f character varying(50),  
  nickname_f character varying(16)
) RETURNS json AS $$  

declare temp_variable users%rowtype;

BEGIN  

  INSERT INTO users (email,nickname)  
    SELECT email_f,nickname_f  
  RETURNING * 
  into temp_variable;  

return row_to_json(temp_variable);

END;   
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

[`RETURNING *`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html)